# what comes first, storage re-use or end of lifetime in placement new?

Tags: c++, object, language-lawyer, lifetime

The standard got the following example to demonstrate that a pointer can only be used in limited ways after the object it points to has its lifetime ended. However, does it mean that the first object's storage is re-used and then its lifetime ends in case placement new is used? Because conceptually storage occupied originally by B got re-used by D, which means the whole [basic#life-6] cannot apply to its example. But looks like there is some loophole in the standard to make the example below valid, which means re-use has to happen *before* its lifetime ends.
[basic#life-6]
.....

```
void B::mutate() {
  new (this) D2;    // reuses storage --- ends the lifetime of *this
  f();              // undefined behavior
  ... = this;       // OK, this points to valid memory
}
```

UPD: Another example is what if storage pointed by this is re-used twice, would using this pointer as void* still be valid? Technically according to the standard does not look like.

```
void B::mutate() {
  new (this) D2;    // reuses storage --- ends the lifetime of *this
  new (this) D2;    // reuses storage --- ends the lifetime of *this
  f();              // undefined behavior
  ... = this;       // Bad? By now STORAGE HAS BEEN RE-USED and [basic#life-6] does not apply at all, which means referring to this shall be invalid now.
}
```

Comment: Link for full context: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6

Comment: Your example is incomplete, it makes no sense as it is.

Comment: @MarkRansom example just shows a sample from [basic#life-6] which relies on placement new to have the sequence: storage re-use -> end of the lifetime of the existing object. My point is where in the standard that sequence is defined?

Comment: Your example doesn't contain a valid sequence, as I said it's nonsense.  The question MUST contain enough to know what you're asking, having a link to somewhere else is not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the example from [[basic.life#6]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6)

When you reach the "undefined behavior" comments, they are signifying that it is undefined because you are accessing the `this` pointer after its lifetime has ended. What you are seeing are examples of *invalid but compilable* code.

Originally, the `this` pointer is a `D1*` pointer, but there is now a `D2` object occupying the memory space that `D1* this` pointed to. In other words, a `D1*` pointer to that same memory location is no longer valid (and thus `pb->f()` is also undefined), but a `B*/void*` to that location is, as it's still a valid memory location. You could potentially make a call to `D2::f()` defined behavior by casting the pointer type:

```
D2* me = std::reinterpret_cast<D2*>(this);
me.f();
```

But simply calling `f()` will not be defined at all within the context of that `#mutate` function, as `this` is still `D1::f`.

Comment: I got the part you are referring to. Later the example shows that you can use **this** pointer as if it is just **void***. The problem with these examples is that [basic#life-6] stipulates that to have any guarantee one must not re-use the storage after the lifetime of the object ended. This can only be true if **new (this) D2** would sequence first re-use and then end of lifetime for *this. My point is where in the standard that sequence is defined.

Comment: I don't think [basic#life-6]  is about another object re-using the original storage - quite the opposite in fact. The main point appears to be covering cases when the lifetime has ended but the storage WAS NOT re-used.

Comment: The lifetime of `this` (as `D1*`) ended the moment that `new (this) D2;` was called. The only situation you'd have where `this` (as `D1*`) having its lifetime ended but storage unused would be during a constructor of `D2`. Rather, the storage was re-used right away, the pointers are just no longer valid. So this example is just demonstrating the usability of a stale pointer after the pointed-to object's storage has be reused.

Comment: yeah but if the storage was re-used then that contradicts pre-condition [basic#life-6], which clearly specify that storage must not been re-used: **Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated22 or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways**

Comment: So the very next line: "For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor]". Basically, what's allowed to be done with the old pointer is the same semantics as what you can do with `this` in the context of a constructor (they're the same pointer, in fact!). So then the following example is the non-constructor case, which follows from the statement "after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or **released**". It's pretty poor wording, this statement applies better when you're not changing the underlying type.

Comment: does not quite get your point. My point is that the whole example must apply to the case when the original object storage is not re-used yet. This means placement new must first be re-used and then end the lifetime, then it would make sense. But it is not clear what happens for the cases when the storage can be re-used, then [basic#life-6]  does not apply AT ALL, and are we not allowed to *this* pointer in any way?

Comment: I think [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) should be used  for `me`.

Comment: @Jarod42 std::launder would only work if the given pointer points to the object within its lifetime

Comment: Which should be the case for `me`...